Build errors when using d3 in a sharepoint 2019 spfx environment
I have a devenvironment setup for Sharepoint 2019/SPSE and i can create webparts but have problem when using d3.js. Adding import * as d3 from 'd3' generates a bunch of type-errors when running gulp build. (sample below of errors).
Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\d3-array\index.d.ts(35,79): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[12:05:27] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\d3-array\index.d.ts(35,94): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[12:05:27] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\d3-array\index.d.ts(48,13): error TS1005: ')' expected.
[12:05:27] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\d3-scale-chromatic\index.d.ts(40,34): error TS1005: '=' expected.


Node 8.17.0
Spfx 1.4.1
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
npm@6.13.4
typescript@3.3.4000
yo@2.0.6

Checking file with error the syntax is correct.
I have tried older version of d3 and d3types. Specifying a specific d3 function in d3 import.
Still get error from functions that isn't imported, ex d3-array.
if i click on a error in console like:
Error - typescript - node_modules/@types/d3-scale-chromatic/index.d.ts(8,40): error TS1005: '=' expected. It seems to have no relation to the error described.
Rows from 1 - 8 looks like this:

// Last module patch version validated against: 1.5.0

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Categorical
// ------------------------------------------------------------
**


An array of ten categorical colors represented as RGB hexadecimal strings.


**/


I've seen errors like these with old versions of tsc and your software stack has some old packages.  Can you upgrade typescript?

Since im aiming for Sharepoint 2019 im bound to use spfx 1.4.1

Problem solved. Even though its solved the main problem is the fact its almost not possible to develope spfx-solutions for Sharepoint 2019/SE in a proper way.
Versions is stuck back in 2018, a build generates about 800 varnings for vulnerabilities/deprecated modules. MS has no intention to update spfx for on premise Sharepoint :-(
My dirty fix was to install older versions of types-files aimed for TS 2.4

Your typescript is most probably not actually 3.x, but 2.x (looks like you have installed 3.x manually - won't work. SPFX 1.4 build tools will use the old version anyway)
Just use a D3 version old enough to build properly with typescript 2.x. I'd say it should be a version at least 3-4 years old (i.e. something from around 2020). Just go backwards in the versions until it builds.

Thanks for reply!
I have tried to use an older version, stopped at v3. Thought it would be old enough.
For example, version 4.10.0 was released 2017

Do you mean still no luck? I have not tried myself. But the error looks like typescript version mismatch.

No luck yet. Tried a lot of older versions of d3 but still get build errors.
Seems to be 3 modules that gives a error.
d3-scale, d3-scale-chromatic and d3-array.
Even though i change import statement to a specific module, import {select, selectAll} from 'd3-selection' still generate build errors.
If i delete the modules mentioned i can build without errors.
I suspect the types for those modules is incorrect?

I would try downgrading d3 even further maybe? Something that is before the typescript version SPFx 1.4 is using (is it 2.2?) - that may be from even before 2017. Looks like my estimate of 202 was too optimistic :D

Finally! I had to back version of the types-files for the modules reporting errors.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3-scale-chromatic?activeTab=versions has tagged version of ts. Im stuck on ts 2.4 :-/ . Its a dirty fix and i dont like working with so old versions. I hope MS will release an update of spfx for SP2019&SPSE...
